# How to change n distinct global variable using function with parameters in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def change(a):
   a=4
print('1:')
c=3
print('Value before changing',c)
change(c)
print('Value after changing',c)
print('2:')
d=6
print('Value before changing',d)
change(d)
print('Value after changing',d)
print('3:')
e=7
print('Value before changing',e)
change(e)
print('Value after changing',e)
```

I want to change n distinct global variables. Eg: I want to change c,d and e global variables using function by passing it as a argument. How can I do so?

Comment: You need to tell `change` that they are global variables.  (And fix your indentation.)

Comment: Note, this is generally not a good thing, mutable global state is bad

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

My original answer wouldn't have worked. So here's my new answer. First, you'll need a function to get the name of the variable. This can be done with the builtin `inspect` package like so,

```
import inspect

def retrieve_name(var):
    callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()
    return [var_name for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars if var_val is var]
```

Then, you'll need to rewrite your change function to

```
def change(a):
    globals()[a] = 4
```

And use it in conjunction with the `retrieve_name` function like so,

```
change(retrieve_name(x)[0])
```

Because if you just put the `retrieve_name` inside `change` it will always return `a`.

**Below is my original answer:**

Tell the function `change` that `a` is global. Eg:

```
def change(a):
  global a
  a = 4
```

Comment: But I want to change global variables many times not one or two times . According to your answer I have to update my function everytime I change new global variable .

Comment: Please suggest some constant function

Comment: @PratikGoud I've updated my answer. This should work now

Answer (score 0):

the *global* keyword tells the function that there already exists a variable of this name, defined outside the current scope. It is in, what python calls, the global scope (think the outter-most scope of a python file).

```
>>> def change(a, value=4):
        global a
        a = value

>>> x = 3
>>> change(x)
# x = 4
```

Comment: It's showing :Syntax error: name 'a' is parameter and global.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my previous answer so that it should work, but here is an alternative method.

```
def change(**kwargs):
    for name in kwargs:
        globals()[name] = 4

x = 3
change(x=x) # whatever follows the '=' sign is redundant in this case
```

Or, you could do

```
def change(**kwargs):
    globals().update(kwargs)

x = 3
change(x=4) # the global value of 'x' is now 4
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcus Weinberger